# Moving Oracle / Oracle datafiles to different file system on Linux

Tags: oracle, linux, migration, oracle-12c

We have Oracle installed on `/root`, which is now running out of space due to increasing data in Oracle database. On the same machine we have another file system with free space.

I want to know the mechanism by which we can move Oracle / Oracle data files to this new file system and continue to use the same data files.

Appreciate any formal steps reference.

It is Oracle 12c on RHEL

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way, in 12c, you can move datafiles online, e.g:

```
alter database move datafile '/current_fs/system01.dbf' to '/another_fs/system01.dbf';
```

Comment: Thanks , also I got more details ar https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/renaming-or-moving-oracle-files